# Creating custom Linux 32bit image in Azure

Tags: image, azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, 32-bit

I exported a custom VirtualBox (Ubuntu 12.04, 32bit)image and want to recreate this in Azure.

- I converted the image to VHD and uploaded it to storage blobs. But when I want to create a new Azure Image from this blob, I get the error 'Only blobs formatted as VHDS are supported'
- I also tried installing VirtualBox into an new Azure Vm and running the image there, but the VirtualBox seems to overtake the Network from the Azure VM and therefore disconnecting it.
- I read that Azure VM doesn't even support Linux 32bit versions. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021388/support-for-32-bit-operating-systems-in-azure-virtual-machines

Did anyone ever run into this problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Azure doesn't support 32 bit OSs so you'll need to do 64 bit, or, another option, you can run a VM that supports Nested Virtualization, in which case you can run a 32 bit VM on top of that.